# Inline/combine other collection into one collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to combine two mongodb collections.

Basically I have a collection containing documents that reference one document from another collection. Now I want to have this as a inline / nested field instead of a separate document.

So just to provide an example:

Collection A:

```
[{
    "_id":"90A26C2A-4976-4EDD-850D-2ED8BEA46F9E",
    "someValue": "foo"
  },
  {
    "_id":"5F0BB248-E628-4B8F-A2F6-FECD79B78354",
    "someValue": "bar"
  }]
```

Collection B:

```
[{
    "_id":"169099A4-5EB9-4D55-8118-53D30B8A2E1A",
    "collectionAID":"90A26C2A-4976-4EDD-850D-2ED8BEA46F9E",
    "some":"foo",
    "andOther":"stuff"
  },
  {
    "_id":"83B14A8B-86A8-49FF-8394-0A7F9E709C13",
    "collectionAID":"90A26C2A-4976-4EDD-850D-2ED8BEA46F9E",
    "some":"bar",
    "andOther":"random"
   }]
```

This should result in Collection A looking like this:

```
[{
    "_id":"90A26C2A-4976-4EDD-850D-2ED8BEA46F9E",
    "someValue": "foo",
    "collectionB":[{
            "some":"foo",
            "andOther":"stuff"
            },{
            "some":"bar",
            "andOther":"random"
            }]
  },
  {
    "_id":"5F0BB248-E628-4B8F-A2F6-FECD79B78354",
    "someValue": "bar"
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something simple like this from the console:

```
db.collB.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    var aid = doc.collectionAID;
    if (typeof aid === 'undefined') { return; } // nothing
    delete doc["_id"]; // remove property
    delete doc["collectionAID"]; // remove property
    db.collA.update({_id: aid},   /* match the ID from B */
       { $push : { collectionB : doc }});
});
```

It loops through each document in **collectionB** and if there is a field `collectionAID` defined, it removes the unnecessary properties (`_id` and `collectionAID`). Finally, it updates a matching document in **collectionA** by using the `$push` operator to add the document from **B** to the field `collectionB`. If the field doesn't exist, it is automatically created as an array with the newly inserted document. If it does exist as an array, it will be appended. (If it exists, but isn't an array, it will fail). Because the `update` call isn't using `upsert`, if the `_id` in the **collectionB** document doesn't exist, nothing will happen.

You can extend it to delete other fields as necessary or possibly add more robust error handling if for example a document from **B** doesn't match anything in **A**.

Running the code above on your data produces this:

```
{ "_id" : "5F0BB248-E628-4B8F-A2F6-FECD79B78354", "someValue" : "bar" }
{ "_id" : "90A26C2A-4976-4EDD-850D-2ED8BEA46F9E",
    "collectionB" : [
            {
                    "some" : "foo",
                    "andOther" : "stuff"
            },
            {
                    "some" : "bar",
                    "andOther" : "random"
            }
    ],
    "someValue" : "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly mapreduce can't produce full documents. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517

No idea why despite all the attention, whining and upvotes they haven't changed it. So you'll have to do this manually in the language of your choice.

Hopefully you've indexed 'collectionAID' which should improve the speed of your queries. Just write something that goes through your A collection one document at a time, loading the _id and then adding the array from Collection B.

Comment: MapReduce would still be a poor fit for this as it's trying to do a complex merge.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much faster way than https://stackoverflow.com/a/22676205/1578508

You can do it the other way round and run through the collection you want to insert your documents in. (Far less executions!)

`db.collA.find().forEach(function (x) {
     var collBs = db.collB.find({"collectionAID":x._id},{"_id":0,"collectionA":0});
     x.collectionB = collBs.toArray();
     db.collA.save(x);
})`

Comment: While it's maybe faster (which was difficult to tell from the limited information you provided), it's not as robust, nor does it clean up the data as was suggested by your question's examples.

Comment: To clean up you could do "db.collB.find({"collectionAID":x._id}, {"_id":0,"collectionA":0})" instead of "db.collB.find({"collectionAID":x._id})" And the "if (typeof aid === 'undefined') { return; }" could be done via "db.collA.find("aid":{"$exists":true}).....

Comment: I know it is difficult to tell by the answer provided, but usually when you reduce an array of documents from B into one document in A it should be faster fetching arrays of documents while iterating over A instead of iterating over each document in B and pushing it onto the document in A

Comment: You're answer was absolutely correct and helped me getting to this point :)